# No sound using Asus xonar DGX

Tags: 12.04, drivers, sound, asus, soundcard

I've just bought a new sound card, Asus xonar DGX, and it works perfectly in Windows 7.

However, when I load up 12.04, I get no sound whatsoever. I went into **System Settings** → **Sound** and there was nothing in the "**play sound through**" box.

Does anybody know how I can get my sound to work?

Answer (score 1):

Currently it seems that it doesn't work with ubuntu 12.04. However, it works with [kernel 3.5 or with alsa driver 1.0.26](http://www.alsa-project.org/main/index.php/Matrix%3aVendor-Asus) (which isn't released yet). I have the same soundcard and I guess we'll have to wait either for updates for ubuntu 12.04 or wait for the next distro of Ubuntu, quantal, that will support the soundcard, since it will use kernel 3.5.
Cheers

Comment: 3.5 can be installed via PPA. You can remove the PPA after testing with `ppa-purge`. https://launchpad.net/~xorg-edgers/+archive/ppa

Answer (score 1):

Add the X-Swat Backports QTS PPA and install the Quantal kernel which is regularly updated.  Do so at your own risk, but I've been doing this for a while without an issue.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-x-swat/q-lts-backport
```

And then look in Synaptic for quantal-lts-kernel and install it.